# How to access Controls in Update Panel by using JQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, web-services

I would like to perform an autocomplete by using jquery with webservice for the textbox control "txtAbc" in a repeater "repAbc" within an updatepanel. The autocomplete function works only before the postback of the updatepanel. After postback, it is not functioning.

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
     <asp:Repeater ID="repAbc" runat="server" OnItemCommand="repAbc_ItemCommand"
 OnItemDataBound="repAbc_ItemDataBound">
          <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:TextBox ID="txtAbc" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
       </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
  </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $("[id$=txtAbc]").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Services.asmx/GetAbcMethod") %>',
                    data: "{ 'prefix': '" + escape(request.term) + "', 'varType':'eqType'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                value: item
                            }
                        }));
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 1
        }); });
</script>
```

Comment: Your textbox ID in markup is `txtAbc`, your jquery selector is `id$=txtEqType` is this a typo or this is your real code?

Comment: txtAbc or txtEqType?

Comment: do you get any errors in console, i think you should change your selector to something like $( "input[id$=txtEqType]" ). as @neel said i suppose it should be txtabc inplace of txtEqType

Comment: I would like to apologize for my typo. All my code run well no error occur i suspect that it couldn't found my control in my repeater. Any Help? Thank You.

Comment: try adding  clientidmode="Static" in <asp:TextBox @WeiThengTwt

Comment: take $("#txtAbc") instead of $("[id$=txtAbc]")

Comment: After i tested by removing the updatepanel and added ClientIDMode="Static" in <asp:TextBox/> the autocomplete function works for both  $("#txtAbc") or $("[id$=txtAbc]"). How can i make the autocomplete works with updatepanel? @Neel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding a pageLoad() function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function pageLoad() {
      $(function () {
         // Textbox Autocomplete function here...
      });
  }
</script>
```